# Multiple Cursors for Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

How can I use multiple cursors in Netbeans?

I am watching HTML video series to help brushup on my HTML skills. I've just started using Zen Coding which is pretty awesome, but I can't find a way to use multiple cursors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This feature was added in Netbeans 8.2.

From the [Netbeans changelog](http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/index.php?title=NewAndNoteworthyNB82&oldid=69906#Editor_Multicarets):

Add cursor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer to my really old question! I've long stopped using Netbeans, but I'm sure other people will find this useful. I've made your answer the accepted one. Cheers.

Comment: Is there any way that the multiple cursors could get disabled?
I cannot find the hotkey in preferences and Ctrl Shift Click does a normal Shift select operation only.

Comment: Thanks, is there some shortcut to customize this function? I've been years using **Ctrl+ Click** on Notepad++.

Answer (score 5):

In Netbeans 7.3.1 you can do rectangular select, which functions like multiple cursors as long as all the cursors are in one column.

To enable it, press Ctrl-Shift-R or click this button: 
[image]

Then you can drag a box or a column to select all of it.  If you start typing, you'll have one cursor per row.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet unfortunately (NB 8.0.2) but, good news! It has been requested [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200027) and it's being implemented.
You can see the preview on an experimental build [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/preview_multicursor_selection_in_netbeans1)

Comment: Woah this question is 4 years old! These days I just prefer to use Vim.

Comment: There is an activity in the ticket https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200027 so I hope we will see the feature in a production version soon. Guys are doing a good job ;)

Answer (score 1):

Multicarets were introduced in Netbeans 8.2, see their website:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB82#Editor_Multicarets