# shortcuts for netbeans to select next word for multiple editing

Tags: netbeans-7

Is there any shortcuts to select next word in netbeans?

Like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>  in [Sublime text](https://gist.github.com/eteanga/1736542)  select word (repeat select others occurrences in context for multiple editing)

Answer (score 29):

In netbeans you can use `CTRL + J` (in MacOSX `CMD + J`).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869089

Comment: Working in version 8.2 :)

Answer (score 8):

Working version 8.2

Windows **`CTRL + J`**

MacOSX **`CMD + J`**

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same thing but if you are in a supported programming language you can use Ctrl + R to refactor variable's, funciton names, class names etc.